# cannot set property 'exports' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, intern

I have absolutely no clue why node.js makes including files from other files so difficult.

I have a file called file_handler.js

```
exports = {};
exports = {
    upload_file: function (fileUploaderPath, filename) {
        var child_process = require('intern/dojo/node!child_process');
        child_process.spawn(fileUploaderPath + ' ' + filename);
    }
};
```

I would expect something like

```
var file_handler = require('./file_handler.js');
file_handler.upload_file(a,b);
```

to work. But I'm getting an "undefined is not a function" for upload_file(). I tried combinations of module.exports = {...} and exports = {...}. module and exports aren't even defined in my file_handler.js, so I have to set exports = {}; Which makes no sense to me since 99% of the examples on Google use module.exports as built-in.

Comment: Would it be possible to show the entire `file_handler.js` file, or at least how it begins and ends?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, apparently it's because I need to load it as an AMD module.

module.exports = {...} is the CommonJS way.

define(function() {...}); is the AMD way (which I needed to use).

Comment: Could you provide a complete example for using `define` for `upload_file`?

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
module.exports = {
    upload_file: function (fileUploaderPath, filename) {
        var child_process = require('intern/dojo/node!child_process');
        child_process.spawn(fileUploaderPath + ' ' + filename);
    }
};
```

I have just tried this and it worked.

Alternatively, you can do something like this:

```
exports.upload_file=function (fileUploaderPath, filename) {
  var child_process = require('intern/dojo/node!child_process');
  child_process.spawn(fileUploaderPath + ' ' + filename);
};
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried those, but when I run my code it says module is undefined (for the first example), and exports is undefined for the second example.