# Correct way to export/define functions in Electron's Renderer

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, amd

I have a JS file that I'm importing into my Electron's "[main](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/glossary.md#main-process)" (or background process), `app.js`, using `require` (eg: `const myJS = require("./pathToMyJS/myJS");`)

Contents of `myJS.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  mFunc: function mFunc(param1) {
    ...
  }
};
```

And I can use `mFunc` in `app.js` as `myJS.mFunc(param1);` & everything's great.

Then, I tried to follow the same process for the "[renderer](https://electronjs.org/docs/glossary#renderer-process)" JS. So my `renderer.js` now imports `const myOtherJS = require("./myJS/myOtherJS");` where this other JS file follows the exact same `module.exports` logic as `myJS`.

And the root HTML (`app.html`) declares the `renderer` as `<script defer src="./renderer/renderer.js"></script>`.

But on launch, I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'exports' of undefined
at renderer.js? [sm]:34
```

Searching online, I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33099764/1392578) that mentions that the AMD way could be used instead of the commonJS way. So I tried the following: (not sure whether this is syntactically correct!)

```
define(
  ["renderer"],
function rFunc(param1) { 
  ... }
)
```

But that fails with:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
```

So what's the correct way to have functions defined for export when using them in the renderer? What I've been doing so far is just to write the functions in their own JS files (eg: `function func1() { ...}`) & declaring all of these files in the `app.html` as `<script defer src="./funcFile1.js"></script>`.

Comment: You may find this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37736836/1244884) useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, I was just exporting incorrectly. `modules.export` was the point of failure as `modules` is undefined on the `renderer`.

Instead, if I do the following to export individual functions:

```
// ./myJS/myOtherJS.js
export function rFunc() { ...}
```

And then import into my `renderer.js` like:

```
import { rFunc } from './myJS/myOtherJS';
rFunc();
```

Things work as I originally expected.

This [Google Developers Primer](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/modules) on modules was useful in understanding the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

AMD is not provided by node.js by default. It's used by Require.js and other FWs. Here is a link on how you can use it with node:

https://requirejs.org/docs/node.html